# Reading .dat file date string

Tags: python, string, date

In Python:

Got a .dat file one column is a datestr 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Column years range from 2000, to 2010 I only want to use 2005.

How can I successfully read using np.loadtxt, keeping in the same format.

I am then going to use:

```
time_string = yyyy-mm-dd
doy = int (time.strftime ("%j", time.strptime ( time_string, "%Y, %m, %d")))
```

to convert yyyy-mm-dd to day of year (1-365)

Comment: what language are you using? C++? C?

Comment: Ohh, my bad my bad. Python- I'll Edit. Thanks

Comment: add the python tag in this question

Comment: Done - sorry I am new to this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't point any reason to the use of `loadtxt` from `numpy`, so you actually don't care about how your data is loaded. Said that, in this case you simply use `dtype=object` for loading it.

Suppose this is your .dat file, let us call it d1.dat:

```
1 2000-01-01 blah
2 2005-01-01 bleh
3 2006-02-03 blih
4 2008-03-04 bloh
5 2010-04-05 bluh
6 2005-03-12 blahr
```

Then (for example) to load it using `numpy`:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.loadtxt('d1.dat', usecols=[1,2], dtype=object)
```

Now you can apply your function to extract the day of the year from the first column in data:

```
for date, _ in data:
    print time.strftime("%j", time.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
time_string = '2012-12-31'
dt = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
print dt.timetuple().tm_yday


366
```

Comment: Thanks, But how do I loop over the file to extract the columns (datestr) keeps telling me its not float - which i know, but cant convert it to a float due to its form.

 .dat file looks like this: http://www2.geog.ucl.ac.uk/~plewis/geogg122/python/delnorte.dat

I only want to extract 2005, and save column 3 and 4, in the form of:

Day of Year | Column 4

Comment: This was not your question. At least you did not provide any reasonable information about the .dat file...ask that in a new question or be clear about what you have, what you want and what your real problem is.

Comment: What have you tried to read and iterate through the file? The file is a standard file and can be read using standard Python file operation methods...

Comment: I was using np.loadtxt('filename', usecols=[2,3]. But got ValueError:invalid literal for float(): 2000-01-01.

Comment: Please post a new question with related code etc..the parser question is off-topic for this quesiton